# Are PRC and MOBI files identical?

Tags: ebook, mobi

Are PRC and MOBI files identical? If I make a working file with the extension .prc have the extension .mobi will it work just as well? The changing of file extension works when I've tested it, and I've found sources say they are, but not perfectly reputable ones

(I ask because we plan to sell these files, and I feel people recognise what MOBIs are better.)

Comment: I should add, in case no one answers but others find this question, that they appear to be; the changing of file extension works when I've tested it, and I've found sources say they are, but not perfectly reputable ones.

Comment: You should edit the question with additional information instead of using a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

( http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI )

> MOBI is the format used by the MobiPocket Reader. It may have a .mobi
>   extension or it may have a .prc extension. The extension can be
>   changed by the user to either of the accepted forms.

[...]

> MOBI format was originally an extension of the PalmDOC format by
>   adding certain HTML like tags to the data. Many MOBI formatted
>   documents still use this form. However there is also a high
>   compression version of this file format that compresses data to a
>   larger degree in a proprietary manner. There are some third party
>   programs that can read the eBooks in the original MOBI format but
>   there are only a few third party program that can read the eBooks in
>   the new compressed form.

There are no sources quoted as far as I can tell, but the take-away is that `.MOBI` is an extension or `prc` and some features are not supported by most readers.

Comment: ...which would imply that the answer to 'Are PRC and MOBI files identical?' is no but the answer to 'If I make a working file with the extension .prc have the extension .mobi will it work just as well?' is yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They do use the MOBI format, but PRC files MAY have 'Digital Rights Protection'. If they have DRM protection they won't be usable without the DRM key.